# Matching specific numeric regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match only the `/blog?page=1` (only with `page=1`) and I have written the regex for it that is `/blog\?page=1`

but it is also matching with `/blog?page=11`. Is this possible only to match it with `/blog\?page=1` ?

Comment: why use regex if you only want to match /blog?page=1, you can easily achive this with [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: why you are trying to math with regex, isn't this information available in `$_GET['page']` ?

Comment: I suggest that you do the basic exercises at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com). You will get the grasp of regex basics and will be able to handle such issues by yourself. Pay special attention to [Lesson 10](http://regexone.com/lesson/line_beginning_end) and [Lesson 15](http://regexone.com/lesson/misc_meta_characters).

Comment: @kamalpal Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks I will check that out. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use anchors: `\/blog\?page=1$` . This will assert the position at end of the string.

Now, depending on what your are trying to match, if you are looking for the first digit only, for example, you can use this: `\/blog\?page=\d` . You can also use a capture group, to retrieve just the number: `\/blog\?page=(\d)`.

Comment: This implies there are no other query parameters in the query string.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add end of string character which is `$`